# Mirror modifier not copying faces - just vertices and edges?

Tags: mirror

Please could I request some help with mirror modifiers - I applied one to a model I am working on - but have just noticed it is only being applied to the vertices and edges I create rather than faces as well.

Can anyone explain what might be happening please?

[image]

Comment: The screen capture shows wireframe shading, so it's hard to see the issue concretely.

Answer (score 1):

To preview the mirrored geometry, click on the right button in the header of the mirror modifier: *Adjust edit cage to modifier*.

[image: modifier setup]

[image: toggling the button (gif)]

Answer (score 0):

Leave the *Edit Mode*.

This kind of display is normal for *Edit Mode* to show, that the geometry is mirrored.